# Couldn't install Discord (unmet dependencies)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

**I was trying to install a .deb file(discord)**

while doing so, i met with this error

```
 discord : Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not installed
           Depends: libc++1 but it is not installed
           Recommends: libappindicator1 but it is not installed or
                       libayatana-appindicator1 but it is not installed
```

so i decided to install libgconf-2-4 and met with another error :(

```
 discord : Depends: libc++1 but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed or
                       libayatana-appindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
 libgconf-2-4 : Depends: gconf2-common (= 3.2.6-7ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: gconf-service
```

then tried installing libc++1 and met with the same error

```
discord : Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed or
                       libayatana-appindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
 libc++1 : Depends: libc++1-12 (>= 12~) but it is not going to be installed
```

need help

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="21.04 (Hirsute Hippo)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 21.04"
VERSION_ID="21.04"